# Create a zip of files containing a particular text

Tags: linux, shell

I have 20+ json files in a directory each have an attribute "userType" whose value can be customer or employee, I need to create 2 zips here customer.zip   that will contain all the files that has text "usertype":"customer" and remaining json in employee.zip

I can grep for the text to get the list of file names:

```
grep \"userType\":\"customer\" *.json
```

this gives me the list of json files, how should I pass this list to the zip creation command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep -l` with `xargs`:

```
grep -lZ '"userType":"customer"' *.json | xargs -0 zip customer.zip
```

and

```
grep -lZ '"userType":"employee"' *.json | xargs -0 zip employee.zip
```

PS: `-Z` option in `grep` outputs a NUL byte after each filename and `xargs -0` reads a NUL delimited input. This is used to take care of filenames with spaces, newlines and glob characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anubhava. You made my day :)